# Video Streaming Solution for Apple/Android/Desktop

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I need to stream a video to a variety of browsers and devices, all main browsers, IE 8+, FF, Chrome, Safari and to Android and Apple mobile devices. My videos will be stored on S3/Cloudfront.

I've looked into the options and have come up with HLS streaming, which will work on apple and android devices, and safari desktop.

For other browsers I will use a flash fallback implementation. I know JW player can read a HLS stream in a flash implementation. Does anyone know of alternative free software?

My question is, is there a better approach, what is your solution?

Comment: I haven't seen anything that could compete with JW Player's flash fallback. What solution did you go with?